# User defined function

Tags: mysql

For some reason, I'm having a lot of troubles with this.

Here is the question:

Write a user-defined sql function named `LastNameFirst` that concatenates the employee’s `LastName` and `FirstName` into a single value named `FullName`, and displays, in order, the `LastName`, a comma, a space, and the `FirstName` (hint: Smith and Steve would be combined to read Smith, Steve).  There are many ways to do this without writing a user defined function, but the purpose of this exercise is to write a solution that uses an sql user-defined function.

Here is what I have:

`CREATE FUNCTION LastNameFirst
(LastName varchar(50), FirstName varchar(50))
returns varchar(110)
begin
    declare Fullname varchar(110);

    select CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName)
    from prob5
    return Fullname;`

I'm getting errors all over this thing.. and I don't understand why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot return a result set (ie select) from a function are you sure you want a function and not a procedure?

Comment: Yes, we are asked to write a function :(

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether you want a function or a procedure the normal syntax rules for mysql apply - always terminate a statement with ; every begin must have an end etc. A function would look like this

```
drop function if exists lastnamefirst;

delimiter $$ 

CREATE FUNCTION LastNameFirst (LastName varchar(50), FirstName varchar(50)) returns varchar(110) 
begin 
declare Fullname varchar(110);
 set fullname = CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) ;
return Fullname;

end $$

delimiter ;
```

Note if you are doing this purely in mysql your need to set the delimiter before you create and reset it after.

So given

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | photo     |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | John     | john.png  |
|  2 | Jane     | jane.png  |
|  3 | Ali      |           |
|  6 | Bruce    | bruce.png |
|  7 | Martha   |           |
+----+----------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The function would be invoked like this

```
select id,username, lastnamefirst(username,ifnull(photo,''))
from users limit 5;
```

and the result looks like this

```
+----+----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | username | lastnamefirst(username,ifnull(photo,'')) |
+----+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | John     | John, john.png                           |
|  2 | Jane     | Jane, jane.png                           |
|  3 | Ali      | Ali,                                     |
|  6 | Bruce    | Bruce, bruce.png                         |
|  7 | Martha   | Martha,                                  |
+----+----------+------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Beware of nulls in your data and code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this -

```
CREATE FUNCTION LastNameFirst (LastName varchar(50), FirstName varchar(50)) returns varchar(110) 
return concat(LastName, ", ", FirstName);
```

And then you can use it like this -

```
select LastNameFirst(LastName, FirstName) from prob5;
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Definitely makes sense.  Everything works now.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you. This will help others who are stuck on this same question and come looking for it :)